# Globalize for Currencies

Tags: jquery, globalize3

I have a table in html of prices and I need to change all the prices for a currency (with the currency symbol). I thought use the jquery Globilize (I don't know if is the best... please advice if I'm wrong) but I don't know what to download and where to download!

Someone knows where I can find all the files that I need and how can I use this jquery libs to accomplish these??

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails gem, that'll do that for you. Plus providing currency conversion from a set of public exchange rates.

Comment: I'm using J2EE (JSP), but not ruby!